# Dynamically Create Layout Column for HTML Report Data

Tags: c#, html, razor, razorengine, bulma

I have a desktop application that generates a report in HTML using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) with [bulma](https://bulma.io) for the layout and styling. The data is populated in a column using a foreach loop. When the column gets too long I would like to close the column and continue populating the data in the second column. Initially I thought I could use a counter and close the loop upon reaching a certain count, but as I typed it out I realized that wouldn't work because the loop is inside of a list.

Here is my non-working initial thought....

```
<div class="column">
    @{
        foreach ( var pos in @Model )
        {
            if ( ( pos.Position != null )
            {
                <ol>
                    @foreach ( var app in @pos.Applications )
                    {
                        <li>@app.Applicant.LastName, @app.Applicant.FirstName</li>
                        mcount++;

                        @if (mcount = 25 )
                        {
                            <!-- this was my initial thought, but obviously this is happening inside of an ordered list -->
                            @:</div><!-- close the column -->
                            @:<div class="column"><!-- open new column --><!-- this
                        }

                    }
                </ol>
            }

        }
    }
</div>
```

How can I close the column and start a new one while populating the data and continuing the numbering?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Start attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_start.asp) of the ol tag.

The following should work or at least get you started:

```
<div class="column">
    @{
        foreach ( var pos in @Model )
        {
            if ( ( pos.Position != null )
            {
                <ol>
                    @foreach ( var app in @pos.Applications )
                    {
                        <li>@app.Applicant.LastName, @app.Applicant.FirstName</li>
                        mcount++;

                        @if (mcount = 25 )
                        {
                            <!-- this was my initial thought, but obviously this is happening inside of an ordered list -->

                            @:</ol></div><!-- close the column -->
                            @:<div class="column">
                            @:<ol start="@mcount"<!-- open new column --><!-- this
                        }

                    }
                </ol>
            }

        }
    }
</div>
```